# Buffer Overflow Attack with gets()

Tags: c, linux, unix

I've beening trying to implement a buffer overflow attack on the program below, isThisGood.c, by exploiting the input, see gets(). Without modify the program. By craftinga malicious input that causes a successful exploit. Successful exploit invokes the function, oopsIGotToTheBadFunction, though this function is not explicitly called in isThisGood.c! I've been reading up on them, but it seems like all examples seem to use scanf or strcpy()

This is what I've tried:

```
cc -ggdb isThisGood.c
gdb a.out
break goodFunctionUserInput
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4007ec: file isThisGood.c, line 13.
(gdb) run

Breakpoint 1, goodFunctionUserInput () at isThisGood.c:13
13              gets(buf);

(gdb) backtrace
#0  goodFunctionUserInput () at isThisGood.c:13
#1  0x0000000000400824 in main () at isThisGood.c:19

print /x *buf@40  
$1 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x60, 0x57, 0x60, 0x0, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x50, 0xeb, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x7f, 0x0, 0x0, 0x24, 0x8, 0x40, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x98, 0x3c, 0xd2, 0x70, 0xe8, 0x16, 0xd3, 0x16, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x0, 0x0}

(gdb) print oopsIGotToTheBadFunction
$2 = {int (void)} 0x4007b0 <oopsIGotToTheBadFunction>

echo -e "farmacodependientes\x0\xb0\x07\x40" | ./a.out
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
```

### Bus error (core dumped)

I'm not sure where to go from here, any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int oopsIGotToTheBadFunction(void)
{
printf ("Gotcha!\n");
exit(0);
}

int goodFunctionUserInput (void)
{
char buf[12];
gets(buf);
return(1);
}

int main(void)
{
goodFunctionUserInput (); 
printf("Overflow failed\n"); 
return(1);
}
```

Comment: The bus error is unusual. That usually means misaligned data, like casting an unaligned buffer to a double or an unaligned buffer being used in SSE. The integer unit can usually tolerate it on x86, but not the SIMD unit. You should disassembly your shellcode and show the program and its state.

Comment: I executed this code; and got the expected crash jumping to nowhere.

You attempted to execute exploit code written for a 32 bit processor against a 64 bit program.

In general, offsets can't be ported from one compilation of a binary to another; this is most absurdly unfair. In order to determine the correct offset I would need your binary and a lot of time.

Comment: @jww bus error in Linux can also mean that an area is supposedly mapped with mmap but there is no backing in file.